# spring hibernate database connection

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a trouble of understanding how I can integrate `hibernate.cfg.xml` into my Spring app.
When I created my Spring app, it generated so much xml files which are scattered very where in the application. I try to understand each of very xml; however I couldnt understand how to connect to database with `Spring` and `Hibernate`.

**Web.xml**

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**root-context.xml**:

```
<import resource="db.xml" />
```

db.xml:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>     
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

I tried to modify and changed the db.properties file, but it complained of missing hibernate.cfg.xml

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/table</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the build-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

<!-- thread is the short name for org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Set "true" to show SQL statements -->
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

<!-- mapping class using annotation -->
<mapping class="com.isad.model.Users"></mapping>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

And If I include `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, and run my jsp, I give me

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
```

And this is the class I use to test the connection:

```
    private static final SessionFactory sessionF;
/*private static final ServiceRegistry serviceR;*/

static {
    try {
        sessionF = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }catch(Throwable e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}

public static Session openSession() throws HibernateException{
    return sessionF.openSession();
}

public static void closeSession() {
    openSession().close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    int min = 100;
    int max = 101;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Users aUser = null;
    for(int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        aUser = new Users();
        aUser.setUsername("testusername" + i);
        aUser.setEmail("testemail"+i);
        aUser.setPassword("Hibernate" + i);
        session.save(aUser);

        System.out.println(aUser);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("total: " + (end - start));
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
}
```

this is my stack

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.xml.Origin
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 26 more
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/db.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/xml/Origin
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.xml.Origin
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 26 more

Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/example] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9183"]
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8006"]
Aug 15, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2273 ms
```

Comment: Looks like you miss the  `hibernate-core.jar` in your classpath. Can you checkk please?

Comment: I do have my hibernate-core.jar

Comment: Which version? Can you please add the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @user3819470
`org.hibernate.util.xml.Origin` was removed in Hibernate 4. I'm afraid your project has some kind of stale reference to older version.Try to clean an build again your project

Comment: I think the content inside the db.xml is not correct. But I dont know how to change it so that it can integrate hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @user3819470 Add complete stack trace

Comment: Updated with the stacktrace. So if I without the hibernate-core.jar, my test works but not my jsps

Comment: @user3819470 where is the jar located in your webserver? Do you youse tomcat? Remember the classpath in unittest  and in the runtime enviroment can be different.

Comment: all of my jar is handled by maven pom.xml

Comment: You are configuring a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and you expect a manually configured `SessionFactory` to be testable? You have configured a datasource but aren't inject it into `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. Not sure what you want but your code is every and not really consistent. Do you want to use plain JPA or do you want to use hibernate. Which is it.

Comment: What's your Hibernate and Spring version?

Comment: @user3819470 Please post your `pom.xml` file